# how to access a firefox plugin from terminal

Tags: firefox, terminal, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am wondering if anyone knows how to access a Firefox extension from the terminal. To search from the terminal, we can use

```
firefox --search "hello world"
```

Can we do that for an installed extension? Suppose I have a Timer extension, can I bring up a browser window with the Timer extension opened? I went through all relevant material that I could find, but didn't find a  solution. Any suggestion is appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Might be possible using Marionette for Firefox. Didn't test it myself.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out.